# What is a purpose of Stash in Akka?

Tags: scala, akka

If I am using `Stash` in [spec here](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/Stash.html). I set a config for Stash:

```
 akka{
        actor {
          queued-dispatcher {
              mailbox-type ="akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeueBasedMailBox"
          }
        }
      }
```

1. I suppose that message which went to stash are stored in `UnboundedDequeueBasedMailBox`. Is my insight wrong, if yes what is the real purpose of `UnboundedDequeueBasedMailBox`?
2. Can i get messages which went to `stash`?
3. How did method `stash()` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you use `Stash` trait you are limited to use `UnboundedDequeueBasedMailBox` with it. If you want to use another mailbox type there's another trait called [`UnrestrictedStash`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/index.html#akka.actor.UnrestrictedStash)
2. You could call `unstashAll()` in Scala Api or if you use Java Api there's `unstash()` and `unstashAll()`. In both cases stashed messages will be prepended to the actor's mailbox.
3. If you have a look at the `Stash` trait source, it just uses a Vector to store envelopes (i.e messages). When `unstash()`/`unstashAll()` is called it enqueues messages in reverse order.

Comment: You said do you want me to provide a sample?

Comment: @ Lakshitha Ranasingha thx for your answer, I understood `stash` principle p.s. I made a typo in the previous comment